# MVC5 app doesn't hit my WebAPI2 POST method for creating new records

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC5 application, ASP.NET, that, when creating a new record and clicking submit, it calls my WebAPI (version 2 - the new one) to insert the record into the database.  Problem is, it's not hitting the POST method in my WebAPI.  Anyways, here's my MVC5, front end application code for "Create":

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(BulletinBoard bulletinBoard)
        {
            bulletinBoard.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            bulletinBoard.CreatedBy = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

            response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/bulletinboard", bulletinBoard).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return View("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                LoggerHelper.GetLogger().InsertError(new Exception(string.Format(
                    "Cannot create a new feedback record due to HTTP Response Status Code not being successful: {0}", response.StatusCode)));
                return View("Problem");
            }
        }
```

I already defined "client" in my constructor and gave it the base URL for my WebAPI - keep in mind that `GET` works - so it's not a problem with my URL.  I can also manually go to my WebAPI URL and get data back in my browser.

Here's my WebAPI code:

```
// POST api/bulletinboard
public HttpResponseMessage PostBulletinBoard(BulletinBoard bulletinBoard)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.BulletinBoards.Add(bulletinBoard);
        db.SaveChanges();

        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, bulletinBoard);
        return response;
    }
    else
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
    }
}
```

This worked when I was using WebAPI version 1 which had a different naming convention for the GET and POST and PUT methods.

So, when the URL for the POST request is called (the line that's response = client.PostAsJsonAsync...), the request never hits my POST method in my WebAPI and consequently, no records are inserted into my database.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And what's the status code (`response.StatusCode`) and the exact response payload from the server (`response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`)? You could inspect those in your debugger and evaluate the values (`Shift+F9` and then just type the expressions).

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I'm actually using response.Content.ReadAsAsync() in my Index method to GET the records back from the database - so when I navigate to the WebAPI's GET URL (locahost/MyWebAPI/BulletinBoard), I get back a list of JSON objects representing the data, in my browser.

Comment: I was not asking about what you get in your browser, not what you get for a GET request :-) I was asking you to put a breakpoint on the `if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)` line of your client code and execute what I previously wrote in my comment. I am particularly interested at the value of `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`. Basically this will give you an indication of what the remote server returns in response to your POST request. Chances are the error message you are looking for will simply be contained in this string.

Comment: Sorry, you edited your comment - you asked what I get with my ReadAsStringAsync, if I remember right.  I will put a breakpoint, but if I remember right, it was a 500 error.  Give me a few minutes

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - Sorry, I totally misunderstood you.  I thought for some reason you wanted my GET response contents.  Here's my response content: I think this is pointing me in the right direction as to what the issue is:

Comment: {"$id":"1","Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.","ExceptionType":"System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Http.ApiController.<InvokeActionWithExceptionFilters>d__1.

Comment: MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()"}

Comment: Alright, there you go. You have posted invalid data and the validation simply failed on the server. Will post that as answer. I am sure you will figure it out from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments it appears that you have POSTed invalid data (according to the validation rules you defined in your `BulletinBoard` model) and this validation simply fails. So to fix the issue make sure you are sending valid data.

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be a few reasons why it doesn't hit your post method. Here is my example of Post method. The things you should note is **method name** and **FromBody attribute**

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]FoodProduct foodProduct)
{
      UnitOfWork.FoodRepository.Edit(foodProduct);
      await UnitOfWork.SaveAsync();
      return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

I also like to use this new RoutePrefix Attribute on my controller, it works perfectly and looks good.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Food")]
public class FoodController : BaseApiController
{
   ///some code here
}
```

Comment: You don't need to be using `[FromBody]` for complex types. That's by default and it won't change anything.